# How to display notifications when multiple iBeacons are in range

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon

I have 3 iBeacons which are placed in 3 different rooms. When I walk into each of rooms I'd like to receive a notification while my app is closed that tells me which room I'm in.

My beacons all have the UUID but different major and minor versions.

This is what we've implemented so far in our class (not in App Delegate)

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region {

// firstBeacon is the closest beacon
CLBeacon *firstBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

NSLog(@" Major %@ Minor %@", firstBeacon.major, firstBeacon.minor);

int major = [firstBeacon.major intValue];
int minor = [firstBeacon.minor intValue];

if (major == 43005 && minor == 52679) {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.soundName = @"Default";
    notification.alertBody = @"Green";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    self.beaconColour.text = @"Green";
}
else if (major == 48891 && minor == 47852) {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.soundName = @"Default";
    notification.alertBody = @"Light Blue";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    self.beaconColour.text = @"Light Blue";
}
else if (major == 59510 && minor == 42953) {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.soundName = @"Dark Blue";
    notification.alertBody = @"Green";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    self.beaconColour.text = @"Dark Blue";
}

self.major.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", major];
self.minor.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minor];
```

}

Updated code based on answer

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];

    self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:@"com.accenture.testregion"];


    self.myBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    self.myBeaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    self.myBeaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarnins {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

BOOL _isInsideRegion;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        int major = [beaconRegion.major intValue];
        int minor = [beaconRegion.minor intValue];

        NSLog(@" Major %d Minor %d", major, minor);

        if (major == 43005 && minor == 52679) {

            self.beaconColour.text = @"Green";
            if (!_isInsideRegion) {
                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.soundName = @"Default";
                notification.alertBody = @"Green";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            }
            _isInsideRegion = YES;
        }
        else if (major == 48891 && minor == 47852) {

            self.beaconColour.text = @"Light Blue";
            if (!_isInsideRegion) {
                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.soundName = @"Default";
                notification.alertBody = @"Green";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            }
            _isInsideRegion = YES;
        }
        else if (major == 59510 && minor == 42953) {

            self.beaconColour.text = @"Dark Blue";
            if (!_isInsideRegion) {
                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.soundName = @"Default";
                notification.alertBody = @"Green";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            }
            _isInsideRegion = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Is there something that isn't working in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to get first object from beacons array, you should enumerate it and compare which one is which, sometimes you can receive a signal from few beacons.

I made it work by calling `didEnterRegion:` delegate instead on `didRangeBeacons:` 
You should also create a boolean flag (variable) to prevent duplicate sending of notification. And mark it true inside your if condition when minor/major match and set it to false in didExitRegion:

```
BOOL _isInsideRegion;


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        int major = [beaconRegion.major intValue];
        int minor = [beaconRegion.major.minor intValue];

        if (major == 43005 && minor == 52679) {
            if (!_isInsideRegion) {
                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.soundName = @"Default";
                notification.alertBody = @"Green";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            }
            _isInsideRegion = YES;    
            self.beaconColour.text = @"Green";
    }
        else if (major == 48891 && minor == 47852) {
            if (!_isInsideRegion) {....
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        if (major == 43005 && minor == 52679) {
                if (!_isInsideRegion) {
                     // You can send another notification to inform user that he left the region
                 }
                _isInsideRegion = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for post this. We've tried this and it work perfectly when the app is open but not when the app enters the background or not running at all. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user3626407 It works for me. Have you configured region before you call startMonitorinf... and startRanging... ? region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
        region.notifyOnExit = YES;
        region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

Comment: I've updated the code to show you what we have now. Is this the same as yours?

Comment: @user3626407 yes but you have to remember that when you enter the beacon range you should have the notification but when you leave it the notification not came straight after it can takes a few minutes. The best way to see is this code works is close the app. Turn off the beacon device wait couple minutes and turn the beacon on. Your app should receive the notification raven if it's not launched. Have you switch location updates background mode on?

Comment: If I do an NSLog on the major and minor I get Major (null) Minor (null). is CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region; the correct way to access the major and minor values?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is in the background, you don't get region entry/exit events super quickly.  It can take up to 15 minutes to get a notification.  See here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html